# If image has a certain ALT tag, hide a certain div which is under the same parent div as the image

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have multiple product divs which have the same structure and the same classes.

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="product_image">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="Puppy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image_description">
    Image Description
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <div class="product_image">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="Kitten">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image_description">
    Image Description
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide div with class "image_description" only in case when image under product div have alt tag Puppy.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? If so, please add your code to the question.

Comment: Why do you hate puppies? Also, more seriously, will the `alt` attribute-value be exactly equal to 'Puppy' or does it simply begin with 'Puppy'? Will it always be capitalised in exactly that way?

Comment: David, I forgot to mention it, but it should contain the word Puppy. I used [alt*="Puppy"] for that :)

Comment: BTW, It is my first time asking question here on stackoverflow. I was wondering why I got those thumbs down on my question? :) Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: @user3886370: yes. you did not mentioned the part you tried .

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can find all `.product` element that have elements with `alt=Puppy`. and then find `.image_description` element in it and hide it:

```
$('.product:has([alt=Puppy])').find('.image_description').hide();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sb3p5ovz/)**

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('img').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var a = element.attr('alt');
    if(a == 'Puppy'){
        element.parents('.product').find('.image_description').hide();
    }
});
```